# Access default values of resource from sub routes in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

Here I have a default value under my application resource:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /app
    defaults:
        _module_name: app
```

How can I access `_module_name` value in kernel event listeners when requesting sub url from `app`?

for example `app/home`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it in your controller's action definition and use it as is. Or you can pass `Request $request` to your controller's action definition and get it with:

```
$module_name = $request->get('_module_name');
```

If you are creating listener for controller then your `$request` can be found at `$event->getRequest()` method.

Comment: Thank you it works in controller, but what if I want to access it in kernel.events to prevent someone to access it?

Comment: `$request = $event->getRequest`